# Restsharp XML request

Tags: c#, restsharp

I'm trying to PUT some data over an API with restsharp.

From the manual of the API, the PUT call is made using:
template params
id  string
barcode string

and

query params
a   string
operator    string
c   long

The request should have a custom header: Name = “Content-Type” Value = “application/xml”

Can someone tell me how to use restsharp to post a request like this?

Answer (score 14):

[Rest Sharp Put Custom Header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16572385/restsharp-put-custom-header), this helped me a lot the construction is like

```
request.RequestFormat = RestSharp.DataFormat.Xml;
request.XmlSerializer = newRestSharp.Serializers.DotNetXmlSerializer();
request.AddBody(x);
```

was not working. But when I changed the code block body to

```
request.RequestFormat = RestSharp.DataFormat.Xml;
request.AddParameter("text/xml", x, ParameterType.RequestBody);
```

my solution began to work properly.

Answer (score 3):

```
var client = new RestSharp.RestClient();
var request = new RestRequest(myUrl);
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Xml;
```

Should cause the content type and serialization to work correctly.